# Why PUSHAD instruction stores ESP?

Tags: assembly, x86, hardware

Why PUSHAD instruction bother to store ESP? If I want to use POPAD to restore ESP, I have to know the correct content of ESP before I use POPAD. It seems useless to store ESP in PUSHAD.

Can anyone provide some explanation? Thanks.

Comment: Because that required less transistors to implement it 32 years ago, allowing a simple copy of the register bank.  Quite the opposite today, you should *never* use that instruction.  It was eliminated completely in x64.

Answer (score 2):

According to my research, the `PUSHA` instruction was introduced in 1982 in processor [Wikipedia: Intel 80286](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_80286).

Document ["Intel 80286 Programmer's Reference Manual 1987"](http://www.ragestorm.net/downloads/286intel.txt) explains it's purpose using words:

> ...PUSHA (Push All Registers) saves the contents of the eight general
>   registers on the stack... This instruction simplifies
>   procedure calls by reducing the number of instructions required to retain
>   the contents of the general registers for use in a procedure. PUSHA is
>   complemented by POPA...
>
> ...POPA (Pop All Registers) pops the eight general registers given in the description above,
>   except that the SP value is discarded instead of loaded into SP. POPA
>   reverses a previous PUSHA, restoring the general registers to their values
>   before PUSHA was executed...
>
> ...An interrupt service routine may affect registers other than other IP, CS,
>   and FLAGS. It is the responsibility of an interrupt routine to save
>   additional context information before proceeding so that the state of the
>   machine can be restored upon completion of the interrupt service routine
>   (PUSHA and POPA instructions are intended for these operations). Finally,
>   execution of the IRET instruction pops the old IP, CS, and FLAGS from the
>   stack and resumes the execution of the interrupted program...
>
> ...In general, the system designer is free to use almost any interrupt vectors
>   for any given purpose. Some of the lowest-numbered vectors, however, are
>   reserved by Intel for dedicated functions; their use is specifically implied
>   by certain types of exceptions. None of the first 32 vectors should be
>   defined by the user; these vectors are either invoked by pre-defined
>   exceptions or reserved by Intel for future expansion...

My loose translation is that it should be an easy way to create a snapshot of processor's "state" in a point of time such that it can be examined by exception handlers and appropriate corrective actions taken. Examination of caller's stack frames is one of the things that may be needed.

Once this design decision was made, if was practically fixed and frozen until today because "*fully backwards compatible instruction set*" is typical characteristics of the x86 architecture (see [Wikipedia: x86](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86), [Wikipedia: x86-64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86-64))

---

> delphifirst: Why PUSHAD instruction bother to store ESP?

It does it. Period. Why engineers 30 years ago decided that.. is nowadays pointless question with no impact on programming decisions of nowadays programmers

Comment: Probably because the original implementation used a counter to enumerate the registers, and the code for ESP happened to be in the middle is the count.  In that case, the designers would be force to either skip a count (icky excess logic) or just let the processor useless push the ESP, and use (a smaller amount of icky excess) logic to prevent ESP from being load during POPA. Wild speculation only.

Comment: @IraBaxter [Intel® 64 and IA-32 Architectures Software Developer Manuals](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/architectures-software-developer-manuals.html) still classify `ESP` as "_General-Purpose Register_" and `PUSHA/PUSHAD` were kind-of obsoleted: "_..This instruction executes as described in compatibility mode and legacy mode. It is not valid in 64-bit mode.._"